# Algorithm with beamer package causing nightmares

Tags: beamer, algorithm2e

I have an algorithm which works well with `\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}`. Now I have to present the paper and I would like one slide to be that algorithm, so I do:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% definitions 
\newcommand{\kd}{\emph{k}-d\space}
\newcommand{\kgeraf}{\kd GeRaF}
\newcommand{\geraf}{{\tt GeRaF}\xspace}
% \newcommand{\att}[1]{\alert{#1}}
\newcommand{\att}[1]{{#1}}

% shortcuts 
\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{2em}}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{{\medskip\noindent\emph{#1}}}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.3cm,hmargin=1.5cm]{geometry} % it was hmargin=2.5cm
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx,url}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.90} % ize got latex error here
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\def\real{{\mathbb R}}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Add a period to the end of an abbreviation unless there's one
% already, then \xspace.
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\onedot{\futurelet\@let@token\@onedot}
\def\@onedot{\ifx\@let@token.\else.\null\fi\xspace}
%
\def\eg{\emph{e.g}\onedot} \def\Eg{\emph{E.g}\onedot}
\def\ie{\emph{i.e}\onedot} \def\Ie{\emph{I.e}\onedot}
\def\cf{\emph{c.f}\onedot} \def\Cf{\emph{C.f}\onedot}
\def\etc{\emph{etc}\onedot} %\def\vs{\emph{vs}\onedot}
\def\wrt{w.r.t\onedot} \def\dof{d.o.f\onedot}
\def\etal{\emph{et al}\onedot}
\makeatother

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\SetFuncSty{textsc}
\SetDataSty{emph}
\newcommand{\expr}[1]{$\langle${#1}$\rangle$}
\newcommand{\commentsty}[1]{{\color{DarkGreen}#1}}
\SetCommentSty{commentsty}
\SetKwComment{Comment}{$\triangleright$ }{}
\SetKwBlock{Block}{function}{}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
\SetKw{Return}{return}
\SetKwData{Node}{node}
\SetKwData{Leaf}{leaf}
\SetKwFunction{Build}{build}
\SetKwFunction{Variance}{variance}
\SetKwFunction{Median}{median}
\SetKwFunction{Split}{split}

\Input
{pointset $X$, \#trees $m$, \#split-dimensions $t$, max \#points per leaf $p$
}
\Output{randomized \kd forest $F$}
\Begin
{
    $V \gets$ \expr{\Variance of $X$ in every dimension} \\
    $D \gets$ \expr{$t$ dimensions of maximum variance $V$} \\
    $F \gets \emptyset$  \Comment*[f]{forest} \\
    \For{$i \gets 1$ \KwTo $m$}
    {
        $f \gets$ \expr{random transformation}  \Comment*[f]{isometry, shuffling} \\
        $F \gets F \cup (f,\Build(f(X))$) \Comment*[f]{build on transformed X, store $f$}
    }
    \Return $F$
}

\BlankLine

\Block({$\Build(X)$} \Comment*[f]{recursively build tree (node/leaf)})
{
    \If(\Comment*[f]{termination reached}){$|X| \le p$}{\Return $\Leaf(X)$}
    \Else(\Comment*[f]{split points and recurse})
    {
        $s \gets$ \expr{one of dimensions $D$ at random} \\
        $v \gets $ \expr{\Median of $X$ in dimension $s$} \\
        $(L,R) \gets$ \expr{\Split of $X$ in dimension $s$ at value $v$} \\
        \Return $\Node(c,v,\Build(L),\Build(R))$ \Comment*[f]{build children on $L,R$}\\
    }
}
\caption{\kgeraf: building\label{alg:build}}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

which starts producing errors of that nature:

> LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry.

I have searched for the past 3 hours in the site and applied the numerous answers, but I just can't make this thing compile! Can you?

Comment: till to now I never see that someone use `geometry` packages in `beamer` slides ... do you can't live without this package?

Comment: @Zarko I could surely do, if the code manages to compile and the algorithm to be presented in the slides!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have several errors, I fixed the most important ones. All the `\def` should better be `\newcommand`.

1. Don't load `geometry`, it doesn't make sense, as `beamer` already loads it with its own options
2. Don't load `xcolor`, rather pass the options to the class as shown
3. Don't load `graphicx`
4. Don't load `url`, it's already coming with `hyperref`
5. Since you need a frame, it must be `fragile` because you perform macro definitions in it
6. Use `\footnotesize` or the algorithm will not fit
7. Use `\protect\kgeraf` in captions; probably the definition of `\kd` should be `$k$\mbox{-}d`

Here's a working version.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames}]{beamer}

% definitions 
\newcommand{\kd}{\emph{k}-d\space}
\newcommand{\kgeraf}{\kd GeRaF}
\newcommand{\geraf}{{\tt GeRaF}\xspace}
% \newcommand{\att}[1]{\alert{#1}}
\newcommand{\att}[1]{{#1}}

% shortcuts 
\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{2em}}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{{\medskip\noindent\emph{#1}}}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
%\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.3cm,hmargin=1.5cm]{geometry} % it was hmargin=2.5cm
\usepackage{amssymb,url}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.90} % ize got latex error here
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\def\real{{\mathbb R}}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Add a period to the end of an abbreviation unless there's one
% already, then \xspace.
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\onedot{\futurelet\@let@token\@onedot}
\def\@onedot{\ifx\@let@token.\else.\null\fi\xspace}
%
\def\eg{\emph{e.g}\onedot} \def\Eg{\emph{E.g}\onedot}
\def\ie{\emph{i.e}\onedot} \def\Ie{\emph{I.e}\onedot}
\def\cf{\emph{c.f}\onedot} \def\Cf{\emph{C.f}\onedot}
\def\etc{\emph{etc}\onedot} %\def\vs{\emph{vs}\onedot}
\def\wrt{w.r.t\onedot} \def\dof{d.o.f\onedot}
\def\etal{\emph{et al}\onedot}
\makeatother

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\footnotesize
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetFuncSty{textsc}
\SetDataSty{emph}
\newcommand{\expr}[1]{$\langle${#1}$\rangle$}
\newcommand{\commentsty}[1]{{\color{DarkGreen}#1}}
\SetCommentSty{commentsty}
\SetKwComment{Comment}{$\triangleright$ }{}
\SetKwBlock{Block}{function}{}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
\SetKw{Return}{return}
\SetKwData{Node}{node}
\SetKwData{Leaf}{leaf}
\SetKwFunction{Build}{build}
\SetKwFunction{Variance}{variance}
\SetKwFunction{Median}{median}
\SetKwFunction{Split}{split}

\Input
{pointset $X$, \#trees $m$, \#split-dimensions $t$, max \#points per leaf $p$
}
\Output{randomized \kd forest $F$}
\Begin
{
    $V \gets$ \expr{\Variance of $X$ in every dimension} \\
    $D \gets$ \expr{$t$ dimensions of maximum variance $V$} \\
    $F \gets \emptyset$  \Comment*[f]{forest} \\
    \For{$i \gets 1$ \KwTo $m$}
    {
        $f \gets$ \expr{random transformation}  \Comment*[f]{isometry, shuffling} \\
        $F \gets F \cup (f,\Build(f(X))$) \Comment*[f]{build on transformed X, store $f$}
    }
    \Return $F$
}

\BlankLine

\Block({$\Build(X)$} \Comment*[f]{recursively build tree (node/leaf)})
{
    \If(\Comment*[f]{termination reached}){$|X| \le p$}{\Return $\Leaf(X)$}
    \Else(\Comment*[f]{split points and recurse})
    {
        $s \gets$ \expr{one of dimensions $D$ at random} \\
        $v \gets $ \expr{\Median of $X$ in dimension $s$} \\
        $(L,R) \gets$ \expr{\Split of $X$ in dimension $s$ at value $v$} \\
        \Return $\Node(c,v,\Build(L),\Build(R))$ \Comment*[f]{build children on $L,R$}\\
    }
}
\caption{\protect\kgeraf: building}\label{alg:build}
\end{algorithm}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should change your name to latex-God. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to place the `algorithm` inside a `frame`. Even then the content is too much to fit on a regular slide. As such, I've placed it inside a box - using an `[H]` float specifier - and resized it to fit within the frame height.

[image]

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,svgnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \resizebox{!}{45mm}{\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{$k$-d GeRaF: building}
    \SetFuncSty{textsc}
    \SetDataSty{emph}
    \newcommand{\expr}[1]{$\langle${#1}$\rangle$}
    \newcommand{\commentsty}[1]{{\color{DarkGreen}#1}}
    \SetCommentSty{commentsty}
    \SetKwComment{Comment}{$\triangleright$ }{}
    \SetKwBlock{Block}{function}{}
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
    \SetKw{Return}{return}
    \SetKwData{Node}{node}
    \SetKwData{Leaf}{leaf}
    \SetKwFunction{Build}{build}
    \SetKwFunction{Variance}{variance}
    \SetKwFunction{Median}{median}
    \SetKwFunction{Split}{split}
    \Input
    {pointset $X$, \#trees $m$, \#split-dimensions $t$, max \#points per leaf $p$
    }
    \Output{randomized $k$-d forest $F$}
    \Begin
    {
        $V \gets$ \expr{\Variance of $X$ in every dimension} \\
        $D \gets$ \expr{$t$ dimensions of maximum variance $V$} \\
        $F \gets \emptyset$  \Comment*[f]{forest} \\
        \For{$i \gets 1$ \KwTo $m$}
        {
            $f \gets$ \expr{random transformation}  \Comment*[f]{isometry, shuffling} \\
            $F \gets F \cup (f,\Build(f(X))$) \Comment*[f]{build on transformed X, store $f$}
        }
        \Return $F$
    }
    \BlankLine
    \Block({$\Build(X)$} \Comment*[f]{recursively build tree (node/leaf)})
    {
        \If(\Comment*[f]{termination reached}){$|X| \le p$}{\Return $\Leaf(X)$}
        \Else(\Comment*[f]{split points and recurse})
        {
            $s \gets$ \expr{one of dimensions $D$ at random} \\
            $v \gets $ \expr{\Median of $X$ in dimension $s$} \\
            $(L,R) \gets$ \expr{\Split of $X$ in dimension $s$ at value $v$} \\
            \Return $\Node(c,v,\Build(L),\Build(R))$ \Comment*[f]{build children on $L,R$} \\
        }
    }
  \end{algorithm}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I also removed all the superfluous content that doesn't pertain to this example. Additionally, since this is a presentation, some of the general definitions have been inserted in the code to allow it to compile, especially the use of a `[fragile]` frame.

Note that [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) typically uses `\;` to denote line-endings.

If you're using a different theme, then you might want to adjust the `<height>` parameter in `\resizebox{!}{<height>}{...}`.

Comment: OK good Werner. However the other answer came first, but I will upvote you, thank you!