# Table in beamer says that something's wrong

Tags: tables, beamer

Following this question and its answers: [Algorithm with beamer package causing nightmares](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316386/algorithm-with-beamer-package-causing-nightmares), I am trying to fit a table in the presentation, so I did this:

```
\documentclass[table,dvipsnames,svgnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|cccc|cccc|cccc|} \hline
              & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Sphere $n = 10^3, d = 10^4$} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Klein $n = 10^4, d = 10^2$} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{MNIST $n = 60$k$, d = 784$} \\ \hline
$\epsilon$    &  0    &  0.1  &  0.5  &  0.9  & 0    & 0.1  & 0.5  & 0.9  & 0    & 0.1  & 0.5  & 0.9  \\ \hline\hline
{\tt BBD}     &  1.25 &  1.26 &  1.30 &  1.25 & 0.13 & 0.14 & 0.17 & 0.14 & 187.5 & 184.3 & 185.1 & 185.6 \\
{\tt LSH}     &  0.21 &  0.16 &  0.18 &  0.31 & 0.11 & 0.07 & 0.03 & 0.05 &  1.47 & 69.76 & 48.47 & 14.35 \\
{\tt FLANN}   & 25.0  & 25.4  & 25.5  & 25.6  & --   & --   & --   & --   & 244.6 & 217.2 & 157.3 & 142.0 \\
\geraf        &  0.06 &  0.06 &  0.06 &  0.06 & 0.06 & 0.06 & 0.06 & 0.08 & 8.167 & 8.567 & 8.579 & 8.565 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Build time (s) for three representative datasets. {\tt FLANN} does not finish after $4$~hr, which is indicated by `--' on Klein bottle or build times in gray on SIFT, where we have skipped configuration and used default values. {\tt BBD} runs out of memory on SIFT, as well as {\tt LSH} for $\epsilon = {0, 0.1}$.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, I am getting this:

> LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

How to fix this please?

---

Edit:

If someone can provide another method of putting a table into the presentation with that format, this would also be acceptable, of course!!!

Comment: See [Including large tables in a `beamer` `frame`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38177/5764).

Comment: Are you interested in something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0rWNc.png)?

Comment: Of course @Werner, I am thinking that maybe I should discard one column, which will maybe make the problem easier to tackle...